# Bash global variable is empty in a function

Tags: bash, shell, global, var

I just would like to use `calc` to calculate two global variables that are initialized higher in the code, but as I `set -x` for debug, one of these is empty and I don't understand, what's wrong.

At the top of my source.sh I have these declarations:

```
userValue=""
newSolde="
currentSolde=""

[...]

// check the format of a float number

// subsitute "," to "." for 'userValue' will be given to calc later


chkValue() {

if [[ "$1" == +([0-9])?(?(.|,)*([0-9])) ]] 
then
    userValue=$(echo "$1" |sed 's/,/\./')
    newOp="$newOp $userValue"
    return 0
else
    echo "$1 Montant invalide"
    return 1
fi
}

[...]
```

Here I call the function `chkValue`:

```
getOps(){
[[ "$#" -ne 3 ]] && echo -e "missing args" && exit

currentDate=`date +%a%d/%m/%y`
newOp="$currentDate"

# "newOp" is completed by those 3 functions
(chkOperation "$1" && chkMotif "$2" && chkValue "$3") || exit 1
}

calculateNewSolde() {
    newSolde=$(calc -p -- "$userValue"+"$currentSolde") // ***** here it is ****
}

[...]
```

Here is the result of `set -x` when I call `source.sh -c "a string" 58,6`:

```
+ chkValue 58,6
+ [[ 58,6 == +([0-9])?(?(.|,)*([0-9])) ]]
++ echo 58,6
++ sed 's/,/\./'
+ userValue=58.6 // <--- init there
+ newOp='ven.20/11/15 CREDIT tou hghj 58.6'
+ return 0
+ getCurrentSoldeFrom /iuser/DATABASE/1000/DB_1000
+ database=/iuser/DATABASE/1000/DB_1000
++ grep '^Solde' /iuser/DATABASE/1000/DB_1000
++ awk '{print $NF}'
+ currentSolde=15.6
+ calculateNewSolde
++ calc -p -- +15.6 // <---- ???
+ newSolde=15.6
```

I really would like to understand this.

Comment: Comments in bash are preceded by `#`, not `//`.

Comment: You are running `chkValue` in a sub-shell (because of the `()` wrapping). Assignments can't escape sub-shells. Use `{ ...; }` wrapping for a list in the current shell.

Comment: You don't show the code which does `grep ^Solde file | awk '{ print  $NF }'` but it can usefully be written `awk '/^Solde/ { print $NF }' file` instead.

Comment: thx a lot it's solved the problem. And thx for the grep/awk command !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem arises here:

```
(chkOperation "$1" && chkMotif "$2" && chkValue "$3") || exit 1
```

This causes a subshell, and thus the setting of the value doesn't carry back into the parent process. You should rewrite this using `{}`, which allows grouping without a subshell:

```
{ chkOperation "$1" && chkMotif "$2" && chkValue "$3"; } || exit 1
```

It has been noted that standard precedence rules mean that the use of braces was not needed in this case either, so it simplifies to:

```
chkOperation "$1" && chkMotif "$2" && chkValue "$3" || exit 1
```

Comment: thx Petesh, I didn't know that () make subshell, now I'll be carefull of that !